# Bootstrap upload

Tags: javascript, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a file upload that I'm trying to get in Bootstrap layout. I have the following code:

```
 <form action="{{route('admin_auctions_images', ['id' => $auction_id])}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />
      <div class="input-group">
         <span class="input-group-btn">
            <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                 Browse;
              <input type="file" name="filefield" single>
            </span>
         </span>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
       </div>
       <button class="btn btn-primary type="submit">Upload image</button>
  </form>
```

I have following css file:

```
.btn-file {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn-file input[type=file] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: right;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  background: red;
  cursor: inherit;
  display: block;
}

input[readonly] {
  background-color: white !important;
  cursor: text !important;
}
```

and following JS file:

```
$(document).on('change', '.btn-file :file', function() {
  var input = $(this),
      numFiles = input.get(0).files ? input.get(0).files.length : 1,
      label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
  input.trigger('fileselect', [numFiles, label]);
});

$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.btn-file :file').on('fileselect', function(event, numFiles, label) {

        var input = $(this).parents('.input-group').find(':text'),
            log = numFiles > 1 ? numFiles + ' files selected' : label;

        if( input.length ) {
            input.val(log);
        } else {
            if( log ) alert(log);
        }

    });
});
```

The problem is that once I select the file (for upload), it does not display in the text box. I would expect it to show the selected file.

[image: screenshot2]

I have added the css and js file through gulpfile.js (Elixir). It compiled correctly. The JSfiddle file is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wiwa1978/yxL0n391/)

Note: when I comment out the css and js file from the gulpfile.js and change the form to the below and run gulp again it works (although Bootstrap file is not applied). See screenshot.

```
<form action="{{route('admin_auctions_images', ['id' => $auction_id])}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />
    Browse
    <input type="file" name="filefield" single>
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary type="submit">Upload image</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

See [image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you making sure that your layout file is including it and rendering the path of the include correctly? You could post your blade views and the rendered html in a [pastebin](http://laravel.io/bin)

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces this in jsfiddle or other js sandbox. Need to be sure events are even being triggered. You haven't provided any confirmation of that

Comment: @alariva what good does putting this in pastebin do? If the views weren't included don't you think that would be obvious to OP when the button doesn't exist?

Comment: Can you try doing `input:file` and `input:text`

Comment: @charlietfl: have updated the original post with some screenshots and the JSFiddle (new to this tool so bare with me).

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: i tried this without any other attribute but no help. I updated the original question with a method that works, but doesn't look Bootstrap like

Comment: @charlietfl Yo are right, sorry. My bad.

Comment: As far as fiddle goes works fine there ...after you include jQuery library from `Javascript` dropdown https://jsfiddle.net/yxL0n391/2/  and add bootstrap css as external resource

Comment: Does this form exist when that code is run? or is it perhaps being loaded after via ajax?